# Google forms file upload by USER not by question

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Good morning!  Another Google forms question.  I'm currently working on a lengthy Google form where each submission could entail the upload of about 7-8 additional documents, which are uploaded to my Google drive.  Google automatically sorts the file uploads by question (i.e., all file uploads associated with question 20 go into a folder in my Google drive for question 20).  Is there a way to group all uploads by USER into a single folder?

That way, instead of needing to look in 7-8 different folders in my Google drive to find all the uploads, the uploads would all be in one folder for Johnny S. or whomever.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

#### Strategy:

- Create a bound function in form to trigger on Form Submit
- Get Form response from the event object
- Get all item responses and their titles from the form response
- Item response should be the file ID for upload type items
- Use the file ID to copy/move the file to their respective folders using `DriveApp`

#### References:

- [Form submit Trigger Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4)
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write an onFormSubmit trigger that uses the DriveApp service to get a list of all files under the form's folder / subfolder and moves them to another folder. The script should also remove the files from the original folder since, in Google Drive, it is possible to have the [same file in multiple folders](https://www.labnol.org/internet/add-files-multiple-drive-folders/28715/).

Here's a [snippet](https://ctrlq.org/code/19975-move-file-between-folders) to move files between folders.

```
function moveFiles(source, target) {      
  var files = source.getFiles();    
  // this will get the files in subfolders as well
  while (files.hasNext()) {    
    var file = files.next();
    target.addFile(file);
    source.removeFile(file);    
  }
}
```